# Why Hadoop need that amount of RAM?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, resourcemanager

Hadoop containers needs RAM more that the data size itsef (I am using for testing 0.5GB size of data) actually doubles of it, why it is too much?

And what is the concept of physical memory and virtual memory off containers: sometime you get exception like 100mb of 500mb in physical memory but 2.5Gb exceeds 2GB in virtual memory. Why hadoop is exceeding the virtual memory limit as long as 2 GB basically is enough to run the whole Operating System and to keep all my data in the RAM memory so why 2GB it is not enough?

Comment: I've never seen a hadoop cluster with more RAM than storage. Can you even buy 4 TB of RAM? And put it in the same motherboard as a single 4 TB disk?

Comment: @cricket_007 dear read it carefully I mentioned the data size not the storage size I am running for testing a task on 0.5GB data size. I will mention the size to make clearer.

Comment: Not all data needs to be in memory at once unless you're running Spark or something similar. If you're exceeding container sizes, you simply need to edit the yarn config files for what makes sense in your cluster. 2G is the default max, I believe

Comment: Besides, if you're testing half a gig, you don't need hadoop. My 6 year old laptop could process that ;)

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, but my whole question is why that much memory? and why it is exceeding the memory limit as long as 2GB of RAM is already dedicated and the data is 0.5GB?

Comment: Because YARN requires an application master, and will preemptively create more than one container in the instance that a job fails

Comment: @cricket_007 I know that Hadoop is for big data but I am wondering why it is taking that much ram if there is nothing to do. The operating system itself doesn't take 2GB.

Comment: @cricket_007 that's nice so why the container exceeds 2 Gb and I am specifying the minimum RAM as 256MB and another time 500MB for the container

Comment: 5 containers of 500 Mb is more than 2GB. That's all... I'm not sure what OS you are using, but I'd say more than 1 GB dedicated to it is definitely a safe assumption

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using Ubuntu 14(it is taking 500MB). you mentioned 5 containers but why to create  5 containers if it can not afford and also I specified it clearly in the config files that the maximum memory available in the system to be 4GB.

Comment: @cricket_007 and by the way, what is the difference between physical and virtual. I read that physical is the actual ram necessary and virtual includes also RAM for page files and the size of the virtual is decided by the ratio which is by default 2.1 so why the virtual exceeds 2GB for the sake of pages files.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need more RAM because you have overhead of Java running the mapper or reducer task.  The java heap of that process + the JVM.

This picture from [Configuring Heapsize for Mappers and Reducers in Hadoop 2](https://help.sap.com/viewer/50f26aa0f2044127bc5f6d5ad3d090fe/Cloud/en-US/2e6070ee76b8101480abd76da746ffe7.html) probably best explains this.

[image]

And while your data might all fit into .5 GB (as an example) the data structures used in Hadoop (Java) to represent that data use more and as that data is processed those temporary data structures that are used to calculate the results will use more still.  And since Java uses garbage
collection all those representations might be using heap until garbage collection happens.